# Excpetion while configuring camel jmx in jboss

Tags: apache-camel, jmx, jboss6.x, spring-dsl

I am deploying came jmxAgent in Jboss 6.3.0. Follwing is the code snippet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
          xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
         xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring 
                 http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd   
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util     
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd ">

    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- start : Files import to camel context-->
    <!-- Active MQ message broker -->
    <!-- <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/message-borker/integration-message-broker.xml" /> -->
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/COMMON/database-context.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/CA/job-scheduer-route-context.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/CA/jobs-process-route-context.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/CA/pci-jobs-process-route-context.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/CA/archiving_reports.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/COMMON/powercard-sqlFetcher-route-context.xml" />
    <import resource="file:${FIS_HOME}/COMMON/rest/rest-context.xml" />
    <!-- End : Files import to camel context-->

    <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" trace="true" streamCache="true"
                  lazyLoadTypeConverters="true" id="main">


        <properties>
            <property key="CamelLogEipName" value="com.hp.rcu.rtsp.filemanager.route"/>
        </properties>

        <propertyPlaceholder id="properties"
                             location="file:${FIS_HOME}/COMMON/routes.properties"
                             xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"/>

        <jmxAgent id="agent" createConnector="true"/>

</camelContext>
```

An although the deployment is successful i am able to see the below exception in the logs:

```
13:50:47,163 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel) Exception in thread "Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://205.239.212.91:1099/jmxrmi/camel" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JBAS011859: Naming context is read-only
13:50:47,164 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.requireOwner(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:155)
13:50:47,165 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.jboss.as.naming.WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.bind(WritableServiceBasedNamingStore.java:63)
13:50:47,165 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:248)
13:50:47,165 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:268)
13:50:47,167 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.bind(NamingContext.java:257)
13:50:47,167 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425)
13:50:47,168 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:425)
13:50:47,168 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:644)
13:50:47,168 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)
13:50:47,169 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at org.apache.camel.management.DefaultManagementAgent$1.run(DefaultManagementAgent.java:570)
13:50:47,170 ERROR [stderr] (Camel Thread #2 - Camel Thread #1 - JMXConnector: service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel)         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also I am not able to connect to the above url from jconsole.

Note: The jboss container is not in my local and in another server. So the JMX url is  *service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://uspnsvulx785.elabs.svcs.lxp.com:1099/jmxrmi/camel*

Camel version: 2.23.2

Answer (score 0):

You can check this - http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html.
There is a section for JBoss here which will help you configure it.

Comment: Yes i already did that before implementation. Still getting the exception

Answer (score 0):

Ok for now i have a workaround. Rather than implementing jmx connector in Camel, i have used the connector of Jboss itself. You can see all the mbeans of jboss within it. You will find all the mbeans of camel under ***org.apache.camel***.

It will not fix the above exception but you can monitor camel routes and processors.

Also you can remove the jmxAgent line given below from the camel-context.xml if using the jboss connector.

```
<jmxAgent id="agent" createConnector="true"/>
```